# angular 2 error no provider for "BillingService"

Tags: angular

just making an application in angular 2 in ASP MVC core . have made a component , module and a service . but when invoked , it seems to raise the following error:

```
  Error: Error in ./BillingComponent class BillingComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for BillingService
```

the billing.component.ts file is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { BillingPackage } from './BillingPackage';
import { BillingService } from './Billing.Service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/Billing/billing.component.html'
})
export class BillingComponent /* implements OnInit*/ {
    pageTitle: string = 'Billing Options';
    listFilter: string;
    errorMessage: string;

    packages: BillingPackage[];

    constructor(private _billingService: BillingService) {

    }


    ngOnInit(): void {
        debugger;
        this._billingService.getPackages()
            .subscribe(billing => this.packages = billing,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

}
```

the Billing.service.ts is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { BillingPackage } from './BillingPackage';

@Injectable()
export class BillingService {
    //private _companyUrl = 'api/companies/companies.json';
    private _billingUrl = 'api/BillingPackage.json';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getPackages(): Observable<BillingPackage[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._billingUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <BillingPackage[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getPackage(id: string): Observable<BillingPackage> {
        return this.getPackages()
            .map((billing: BillingPackage[]) => billing.find(p => p.Id == id));
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {

        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

and Billing.module.ts is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { BillingComponent } from './billing.component';
import { BillingService } from './billing.service';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: 'billpackages', component: BillingComponent },
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        BillingComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        BillingService,
    ]
})
export class BillingModule { }
```

the Billing.component.html file is as under:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="packages && packages.length">


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" *ngFor="let package of packages">

        <div class='panel panel-info'>
            <div class='panel-heading'>
                {{package.Name}}
            </div>


            <div class='panel-body'>

                <div class='has-error' *ngIf='errorMessage'>{{errorMessage}}</div>

                <div class="row">
                    <h2> <span class="label label-success"> {{package.AllowedUsersCount}}</span> Users</h2> 
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <h2> <span class="label label-info"> {{package.AllowedItemCount}}</span> Products</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <h2> <span class="label label-warning"> {{package.AllowedTransactions}}</span> Transactions</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <h2> <span class="label label-danger"> {{package.AllowedStoreCount}}</span> Stores</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <h2> For <span class="label label-primary"> {{package.MonthlyCharges}}</span></h2>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

any help appreciated..

Comment: Is the file `Billing.Service.ts` or `billing.service.ts`?

Comment: @Puigcerber Billing.Service.ts

Comment: But your module is importing from `'./billing.service'` or is that a typo?

Comment: Is `SharedModule` exporting `HtppModule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **providers: [ BillingService]**:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'billing',
   templateUrl: 'app/Billing/billing.component.html',
   providers: [ BillingService]    
})
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Can you comment that why you voted down? That will help. Thanks

Comment: thank you for the answer. have added the provider there as well. but that also doesnt seem to work..

Comment: Why would he need to add `BillingService` to the providers of the component when he has already done so in the module?

Comment: He shouldn't add it in the module, it should be in the component and he should add an instance of it to the component constructor

Comment: @AvneshShakya seems to help .. however just another generic query .. it seems that whenever a ts file change is made, we need to restrat Visual studio (using 2015) to see the effect in browser..

Comment: I am not sure but try to add this line: 
`"compileOnSave": true` in config file. Hope will work for you, because The **TypeScript documentation** says it only works with Visual Studio 2015 and with the Atom TypeScript plugin. It also requires TypeScript 1.8.4 or higher. Let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Double check every directory path, in the error says: `inline template:0:0`, so if possible please provide html template code also.

In the `Billing.module.ts` route for `BillingComponent`:

`{ path: 'billpackages', component: BillingComponent }`

should be:

`{ path: '', component: BillingComponent }`

if you assign path for parent components